# Count all the "Good numbers" in a given range

Tags: java, loops, filter

The task is about so-called *Good numbers*.

If a number `%` of each of its digits == 0, the number is good.
The task is to count all the *Good numbers* in a given range. The range is A to B.

For example: `13` is not a good number because `13 % 3 != 0`.

Also we have to skip if a digit is zero.

Another example `102` is a good number because `102 % 1 == 0` and `102 % 2 == 0`.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] input = sc.nextLine().split(" ");
        int[] arrInt = new int[input.length];
        arrInt[0] = Integer.parseInt(input[0]);
        arrInt[1] = Integer.parseInt(input[1]);

        int counter = 0;
        boolean isGoodNumber = false;
        String s = "";

        for (int i = arrInt[0]; i <= arrInt[1]; i++) {
            s = Integer.toString(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < s.length(); j++) {
                if (s.charAt(j) == 0) {
                    continue;
                }
                int result = i / s.charAt(j);
                if (result % 1 != 0) {
                    isGoodNumber = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (isGoodNumber) {
                counter += 1;
            }
            isGoodNumber = true;
        }
        System.out.println(counter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated the code below

You were using `character` in your integer calculations for good numbers and not converting it back to `int`.

Also `isGoodNumber` was set to `false` initially as it should be set `true`

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] input = sc.nextLine().split(" ");
        int[] arrInt = new int[input.length];
        arrInt[0] = Integer.parseInt(input[0]);
        arrInt[1] = Integer.parseInt(input[1]);

        int counter = 0;
        boolean isGoodNumber = true;
        String s = "";

        for (int i = arrInt[0]; i <= arrInt[1]; i++) {
            s = Integer.toString(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < s.length(); j++) {
                if (s.charAt(j) - '0' == 0) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (i % (s.charAt(j) - '0') != 0) {
                    isGoodNumber = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (isGoodNumber) {
                counter += 1;
            }
            isGoodNumber = true;
        }
        System.out.println(counter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first convert a number to a string, then split this string into an array, and then parse each digit back as an integer and check whether this integer divides the original number without a reminder. Example:

```java
int[] goodNumbers = IntStream.rangeClosed(150, 200)
        .filter(number -> {
            // an array of digits as strings
            String[] arr = String.valueOf(number).split("");
            // check if good number
            return Arrays.stream(arr)
                    // string with a digit as an integer
                    .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
                    // avoid division by '0'
                    .filter(i -> i != 0)
                    // if the remainder of dividing a number
                    // by all its constituent digits is '0',
                    // then it is a 'Good number'
                    .allMatch(i -> number % i == 0);
        }).toArray();

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(goodNumbers));
// [150, 155, 162, 168, 175, 184, 200]
System.out.println("Count: " + goodNumbers.length);
// Count: 7
```